# How can I remove BitMap from the allocated memory using GC in android application

Tags: android, bitmap, garbage-collection, imageview

I added a BitmapDrawable as a Background to an ImageView and the Bitmap taking 4MB from the memory, when the user navigate to another activity I what to release the BitMap memory using

> item2.setBackground(null);

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    next = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.next);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);

    //The ImageView I want to set a BitMap
    item2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.item2);

    MainActivity.context = getApplicationContext();

    item2.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Bitmap newImage = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.item2, item2.getWidth(), item2.getHeight());
            BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), newImage);
            item2.setBackground(ob);
        }
    });
}

//Call when the User navigate to another Activity
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onResume();
    item2.setBackground(null);
}
```

The GC doesn't free the Bitmap from the memory (as shown in the image below)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried call `newImage.recycle()` in `onPause()`?

Comment: I get "Cannot resolve method recycle()" error, I think its from API level 10 and lower.

Answer (score 0):

`onResume()` is called when this Activity go to foreground, not when user switch to another activity. I think you should move `item2.setBackground(null)` to `onPause()` method.

Comment: Thank you Rey, I just copy it wrong, in my original code I put the code in onPause(), so the image result is the same. (Edit the question)